# Odoo: Call self.env or another model in Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, model, odoo

In odoo 10, I have a thread calling a method that uses self.env to call a model. But when the system does not let me occupy this and throws an exception like this:

```
Exception in thread Thread-44:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/kunder/proyectos/odoo/addons/kunder_odoo_comercionet/models/models.py", line 97, in update_quotations_thread
quotation_list = self.download_comercionet_docs();
  File "/home/kunder/proyectos/odoo/addons/kunder_odoo_comercionet/models/models.py", line 370, in download_comercionet_docs
new_last_date_db = (self.env["ftp_orders.settings"]).search([])[0].last_date
  File "/home/kunder/proyectos/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 1508, in search
res = self._search(args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, count=count)
  File "/home/kunder/proyectos/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 4193, in _search
self.sudo(access_rights_uid or self._uid).check_access_rights('read')
  File "/home/kunder/proyectos/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 4842, in sudo
return self.with_env(self.env(user=user))
  File "/home/kunder/proyectos/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 781, in __call__
return Environment(cr, uid, context)
  File "/home/kunder/proyectos/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 726, in __new__
env, envs = None, cls.envs
  File "/home/kunder/proyectos/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 111, in __get__
return self.fget.__get__(None, owner)()
  File "/home/kunder/proyectos/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 699, in envs
return cls._local.environments
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 72, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
  AttributeError: environments
```

I handle the thread in a model and the way I handle the thread is:

```
def thread_method(self):
     #This method call other model like this and do some other stuff
     self.env['sale.order'].search([])
def main_method(self):
     threading.Thread(target = self.method_thread).start()
```

I'm debugging the code and if I seat on the main_method, it have the same object self.env that have the thread_method, so I do not understand why it does not works.

How can i request another model in a thread?

Thanks

Comment: Share the full stack trace please

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas the full stack trace is update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For threaded method you need to create your own environment

```
from openerp import models, api
from openerp.modules.registry import Registry 

def threaded_method(self):
    with api.Environment.manage():
```

check this for more https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/stock/wizard/procurement_orderpoint_compute.py#L21

Comment: It works, my method is running in the thread. But I have a problem when I add records in my models, the addition is not throwing error but when I see the sale module in quotations not show the additions that should be created.

Comment: odoo creates environment just for one transaction so when you run method in separate thread normal process will do its work and garbage its environment. while your threaded method is still running

Answer (score 4):

you can find an example how to start a thread in [procurement_orderpoint_compute.py](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/stock/wizard/procurement_orderpoint_compute.py) file from Odoo addons.

```
def _procure_calculation_orderpoint(self):
    with api.Environment.manage():
        # As this function is in a new thread, I need to open a new cursor, because the old one may be closed
        new_cr = self.pool.cursor()
        self = self.with_env(self.env(cr=new_cr))
        scheduler_cron = self.sudo().env.ref('procurement.ir_cron_scheduler_action')
        # Avoid to run the scheduler multiple times in the same time
        try:
            with tools.mute_logger('odoo.sql_db'):
                self._cr.execute("SELECT id FROM ir_cron WHERE id = %s FOR UPDATE NOWAIT", (scheduler_cron.id,))
        except Exception:
            _logger.info('Attempt to run procurement scheduler aborted, as already running')
            self._cr.rollback()
            self._cr.close()
            return {}

        self.env['procurement.order']._procure_orderpoint_confirm(
            use_new_cursor=new_cr.dbname,
            company_id=self.env.user.company_id.id)
        new_cr.close()
        return {}
```

Or maybe better if you consider to use OCA [queue](https://github.com/OCA/queue)

Comment: It works, my method is running in the thread. But I have a problem when I add records in my models, the addition is not throwing error but when I see the sale module in quotations not show the additions that should be created.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_cr = self.pool.cursor()
self = self.with_env(self.env(cr=new_cr))

pdb.set_trace()

id_data=self.env['cw.test.module'].create({'name':self.id})
id_data.master_data()
new_cr.commit()

new_cr.close()
```

use `new_cr.commit()` to commit the new cursor